# What if one application couldn't write incoming voice?

Tags: compatibility, voice-recording

I tried a call recorder on my  Android 7.1.2 phone, but only my voice was recorded, not those on the other side.
Does it mean that my phone doesn't support something or should I try to find an application that may work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find an application that works properly ([Call recorder for Android](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.callrecorder.android/) version 25 from f-droid.org).